Python function Assign values based on another column and then based on the row below
Given a value in a column, I want to assign to this column the value shown in the same row on another column. When this condition is not met, for the blanks, I want them to be fulfilled with the row below.
I want to assign in the column "Newest agreement code" the value in the column agreement code only when the column Old/New = 'New'
When the column Old/New = 'Old' then I want it to be fulfilled with the row below in "Newest agreement code".
The code is not returning anything on the rows where the value in "Old/New" = 'Old'
df["Newest agreement code"] = ""

# Iterate through rows (excluding the last row to avoid IndexError)
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    # Check if the current row's "Old/New" is "New"
    if df.loc[i, "Old/New"] == "New":
        # Assign the current row's "Agreement Code" to "Newest agreement code"
        df.loc[i, "Newest agreement code"] = df.loc[i, "Agreement Code"]
    else:
        # Check if there's a next row (avoid IndexError)
        if i < len(df) - 1:
            next_row_newest_code = df.loc[i + 1, "Newest agreement code"]
            if next_row_newest_code:
                # Assign next row's "Newest agreement code" if it exists
                df.loc[i, "Newest agreement code"] = next_row_newest_code

return df



please provide a clear [mre] of input and the matching expected output

Iterating through DF rows using a for loop is inefficient and almost always avoidable using Pandas. If you provide minimal sample data as a DF constructor then it will be easier to help. Avoid posting images which cannot be used to test/show code.

Most likely you need to use shift to create your condition, then np.where or Series.where to build the new column. Don't use a loop.
